# Axis2 web service error: services.xml not found

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, wso2

I have been trying to deploy a simple axis2 web service onto a wso2 application server but I keep on getting the error:

> Error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The services.xml file cannot be found for the service: /WSO2/wso2as-4.1.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/SomeService.aar

However, a quick peek at that .aar file revealed that the services.xml file was indeed contained in the META-INF folder as needed.

What would cause such an error, and how do I proceed with fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most possible issue here - the aar file is not packed correctly - if you extract out the .aar file then META-INF directory should be at the top level.. If you can share the .aar file then I can have look..

Comment: Hi, thanks you were right. I didn't package the files correctly again after unzipping the .aar file. Selecting the correct files and zipping them directly solved the problem. :)