# trouble creating an axis 2 .aar file: xml/services not found error

Tags: linux, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I am trying to create an aar file using OSX 10.7.5 (as a part of [this](http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html) tutorial). To generate the .aar, I navigate to the directory holding my webservice in my eclipse workspace and type

```
jar cvf FirstWebService.aar ./*
```

This is the command that Apache says to use to generate the aar in their [Code Listing 9 from the apache axis 2 documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-buildingservices.html).

The command creates an.aar -- but something is wrong with the process that I am using to create the .aar because when I go to load the .aar file into tomcat's /webapps I get an .xml/services not found error.

I am not sure what to do to fix this error. If I search my computer's file system for the services.xml file, I can find it in `/path to eclipse workspace/workspace/MyFirstWebService/WebContent/WEB-INF/services/FirstWebService/META-INF`
but I am not sure if this file is supposed to be rolled in to the .aar file somehow or if I can just manually plunk this file somewhere into the apache directory structure to get the thing to run.

Note: I do not think I am manually unzipping or unpacking the aar like in this question.  [Axis2 web service error: services.xml not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257854/axis2-web-service-error-services-xml-not-found) I am just running the command listed above from the apache documentation.

Here is the .aar file

[image]

**note** I am using all of the same versions of the software as in the tutorial -- but I am using OSX 10.7.5 where they use windows in the tutorial. Accordingly, I have changed the make-aar command for windows shown in the tutorial (`jar cvf FirstWebService.aar com META-INF`) into the one shown above. If I just try to run the command from the tutorial  `jar cvf FirstWebService.aar com META-INF` I get the same xml/services not found error. It gives this output in the terminal...

```
com: no such file or directory
META-INF: no such file or directory
added manifest
```

Comment: Could you list the complete structure of your AAR file? Does it contain a services.xml file?

Comment: Okay, that's nothing like a valid AAR file. The `META-INF` directory containing `services.xml` is supposed to be at the top level, and your compiled class files are supposed to start at the top level too, not under `build/classes`. Why are you running the jar command differently from the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. When you type the command to create the aar file you have to be in the directory .../EclipseWorkspace/EclipseProjectName/WebContent/WEB-INF/services. This directory contains /META-INF/services.xml. The process that makes the .aar file must be looking in this folder.